# how to achieve faster tfidfvectorizer loading times from within a django view?

Tags: django, scikit-learn, django-cache, joblib

I have a fitted `TfidfVectorizer` with ~120,000 features which I save to file using `joblib.dump`. I later load that model, from within a django view, using `joblib.load` but it is too slow (takes ~2 seconds). What is the best way to improve the loading speed? Should I cache the model using django's caching framework? Should I compress the model when serializing with `joblib.dump`? Is there a way to load the model into memory once and keep it there rather than reloading it each time the view is called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model does not change between requests, therefore, we want to load it into memory once and leave it there. This can be achieved, in `views.py` by loading the model and assigning it to global variable.

Answer (score 0):

You must load you model in the `apps.py` file and then import that model from apps in your `views.py`. Otherwise the model is loaded again with every request (every time views.py is run). And you should pickle your model to disk using `joblib` rather than the built in pickle library.